# Error en React usando material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Soy nuevo en react y creando una App me encuentro con este error, que no se realmente cuál es y porqué ocurre. Espero alguien pueda ayudarme.

Este es el error:

> findDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode. findDOMNode was passed an
> instance of Transition which is inside StrictMode. Instead, add a ref
> directly to the element you want to reference.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código:

https://codepen.io/dacame77/pen/oNWLEdW?editors=1010

```
import React from 'react' 
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import {
    Typography,
    IconButton,
    Toolbar,
    AppBar,
    Badge,
    SwipeableDrawer,
    List,
    Divider,
    ListItem,
    ListItemIcon,
    ListItemText,
} from '@material-ui/core';
import MenuIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Menu';
import {Notifications, Inbox, Mail }from '@material-ui/icons';
import { Link, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import clsx from 'clsx';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
      flexGrow: 1,
    },
    menuButton: {
      marginRight: theme.spacing(2),
    },
    title: {
      flexGrow: 1,
    },
    notifications:{
        marginRight: 18,
    },
    list: {
        width: 250,
      },
      fullList: {
        width: 'auto',
      },
    
  }));


const Navbar = () => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [state, setState] = React.useState({

        left: false,
    
      });

      const toggleDrawer = (anchor, open) => (event) => {
        if (
          event &&
          event.type === "keydown" &&
          (event.key === "Tab" || event.key === "Shift")
        ) {
          return;
        }
    
        setState({ ...state, [anchor]: open });
      };
    
      const list = (anchor) => (
        <div
          className={clsx(classes.list)}
          role="presentation"
          onClick={toggleDrawer(anchor, false)}
          onKeyDown={toggleDrawer(anchor, false)}
        >
          <List>
            {["Inbox", "Starred", "Send email", "Drafts"].map((text, index) => (
              <ListItem button key={text}>
                <ListItemIcon>
                  {index % 2 === 0 ? <Inbox /> : <Mail />}
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText primary={text} />
              </ListItem>
            ))}
          </List>
          <Divider />
          <List>
            {["All mail", "Trash", "Spam"].map((text, index) => (
              <ListItem button key={text}>
                <ListItemIcon>
                  {index % 2 === 0 ? <Inbox /> : <Mail />}
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText primary={text} />
              </ListItem>
            ))}
          </List>
        </div>
      );

    return (
        <>
            <div className={classes.root}>
                <AppBar position="static" color="secondary">
                    <Toolbar>
                        <Typography variant="h6" className={classes.title}>
                            LOGO
                        </Typography>
                        <div className="appbar--links">
                            <div className="border">
                                <Link to="/">Inicio</Link>
                            </div>
                            <div className="border">
                                <Link to="Categorias">Categorias</Link>
                            </div>
                            <div className="border">
                                <Link to="Publicar-servicio">Publicar Servicio</Link>
                            </div>
                            <div className="border">
                                <Link to="Contacto">Contactanos</Link>
                            </div>
                            <div className="border">
                                <Link to="Login">iniciar sesion</Link>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <IconButton>
                        <Badge color="error" badgeContent={3} className={classes.notifications}>
                            <Notifications color="primary"/>
                        </Badge>
                        </IconButton>
                        <div className="icon--menu">
                            <div>
                                {["left"].map((anchor) => (
                                <React.Fragment key={anchor}>
                                    <SwipeableDrawer anchor={anchor} open={state[anchor]} onClose={toggleDrawer(anchor,
                                        false)} onOpen={toggleDrawer(anchor, true)}>
                                        {list(anchor)}
                                    </SwipeableDrawer>
                            <IconButton edge="start" className={classes.menuButton} color="inherit" aria-label="menu"
                                onClick={toggleDrawer(anchor, true)}>
                                <MenuIcon />
                            </IconButton>
                                </React.Fragment>
                                ))}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </Toolbar>
                </AppBar>
                
            </div>
        </>
    )
}


export default withRouter(Navbar);
```

Answer (score 0):

El error que esta visualizando es esperado, dado a que esta usando la versión de Material-UI v4.x junto con [React.StrictMode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html) que resalta errores potencialmente peligrosos en una aplicación. En dicha versión de Material-UI se usan apis que para React ya están deprecadas.

Puede hacer dos cosas:

1. Eliminar el uso de `React.StrictMode` en su código (No es recomendable hacer esto).
2. Actualizar a MUI v5, dado que en esa versión este problema ya estaría resuelto.
3. No hacer nada, los errores que envía `React.StrictMode` son solo en modo de desarrollo, en una compilación de producción esto no será visible en la consola.

- Acá puede rastrear más sobre el issue https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/13394